# Nike + iPod app like customisation?

Tags: iphone, customization, ipad

I am very much curious  about Nike + iPod app look and feel.

- **They have selected `uitabbar` buttons red in color**
- **The `tableviewcell` selection style as red in color.**
- **The disclosure indicator is also red in color.**

The solution in my mind for two of these is:

**I can use a red colored arrow image to use it as accessory view.**

**I can flip between a red colored and white colored view with animation for having the selection style**

But I am clueless of how the tabbar thing is to be done.

I am very curious to know the tricks behind this, I also accept that I may be wrong with my other two solutions. So please suggest the solution for any of the problems. I think all are worth knowing for the developers.

Thanks,

Madhup

Comment: could you add image to indicate what you're trying to achieve? I've been messing with tabbar customization, maybe would be able to help

Comment: ah, sorry - now i see this post is from 2010, never mind :)

Answer (score 2):

It's a private API on the tab bar controller class. It allows you to set a colour to use when a tab bar icon is highlighted. It's default is the blue you normally see.

However, since Nike + iPod is very closely related to Apple itself (having been on prior iPods) and I suspect its also developed by Apple itself, they have access to these private API's that we don't. And to make things worse, if we expose them, we get rejected from the App Store.

Comment: Well I was expecting this answer that they are using private api. I was asking of some workarounds if any exist. By the way I didn't get from the line: "And to make things worse, if we expose them, we get rejected from the App Store."

Comment: I meant that any iPhone apps that expose and use the private APIs will be rejected by Apple, and not allowed to be on the App Store. As for workarounds, the only option is to write your own implementation.